# Reset Facebook Permissions iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, permissions

After finishing my project I want to share it as an *.ipa. Before doing so, I want to check if the Facebook Login thing works.

Until now, I'm always logged in with my Facebook account.

So: Is there a way to reset the Facebook permissions for my iPhone that I can simulate a clean install on my iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to delete that permissions given for that app in facebook site only. setting for that app will be in account or privacy settings in facebook site

Comment: In addition to what @RA said, you'll probably want a clean install of your app as well

Comment: Could you maybe write this as an answer that I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reset permission by calling below methods.

```
- (void)fbDidLogout {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[facebook invalidateSession];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

}

This may force user to re login for facebook.

Comment: How do you make it so the native dialogs come back up? As if the app was installed fresh?